# I am sending transactional emails and I do not need to unsubscribe. How to prevent unsubscribe from appearing at the bottom?

Tags: sendgrid

I am sending transactional emails and I do not need to unsubscribe. How to prevent unsubscribe from appearing at the bottom

Comment: Similar question for Mailjet, though I want to suppress the 'List-Unscribe' email headers.  I'm sending this with standard Python program: https://dev.mailjet.com/email/guides/send-api-v31/